# Host Private Custom Theme

Tags: theme-development, themes, hosting

How can I write and privately host (?) a custom theme in such a way that it can be updated through the built-in Wordpress updater, for several sites that I own myself?

I would like to use a site manager to control which sites are getting theme updates when, without having to log onto each site.

The Git-uploader only seems to work if you manually navigate to each site's wp-admin area.
Any ideas?

Comment: Note that the answer to this will depend on wether you are using v5.8+ or if you're using older versions. v5.8 adds features that makes this much easier. Also note that the requirement for a site manager sounds like a recommendation, I strongly recommend you remove that from your question as recommending software is off topic here, and better done on the software recommendations stack. Also what is the git uploader that you referred to?

Comment: It is 5.8+. https://github.com/afragen/git-updater

Comment: Ok, just bare in mind that 5.8 isn't out yet, but it does add update related features. As for the git updater, if it doesn't auto-update unless you visit WP Admin that's something that they could fix at their end, you should raise an issue, and that might work better for you. Right now there is no canonical answer for this, but 5.8 may add one, it may not satisfy your needs though

Comment: Ah, I'm running the latest version. Since you asked if it's 5.8+ I assumed it was possible to use and therefore, at least, what I used.

Comment: You'd still be able to use `git-updater` after 5.8. On closer inspection, it seems the `Update URI` header is only available for plugins in 5.8, not themes, see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/50921

Comment: of relevance https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14179